# In vim plugin CoC, how to change coc-clangd source priority?

Tags: autocomplete, neovim, coc.nvim, clangd

How to change `coc-clangd` source priority?

I use vim conqueror of completion with language server client `coc-clangd` as autocompletion source and I would like to lower its priority from 99 to 70. I cannot find how to do in the doc.
I tried the following without success `:CocConfig` and then:

```
  "suggest.languageSourcePriority": 70,
  "coc.source.clangd.priority": 70,
  "clangd.priority": 70,
```

To check the current priority I do `:CocList, sources, TAB, refresh` and it always show:

```
* clangd [LS] .<>:"/* 99
```